# GitLab search and graph fail on large repo

Tags: git, nginx, gitlab

Just loaded a large code tree into GitLab and when I do a search I get "500 Something went wrong" error.  When I try to load a graph it errors with "Failed to load graph."  The only commit in the repo is the initial one.  According to `git ls-files |wc -l` there are 46199 files in this repo.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's some info from GitLab:

```
[git@code gitlab]$ bundle exec rake gitlab:env:info RAILS_ENV=production

System information
System:     CentOS 6.4
Current User:   git
Using RVM:  no
Ruby Version:   2.0.0p247
Gem Version:    2.0.3
Bundler Version:1.3.5
Rake Version:   10.1.0

GitLab information
Version:    6.4.3
Revision:   42131d0
Directory:  /home/git/gitlab
DB Adapter: mysql2
URL:        https://code.example.edu/gitlab
HTTP Clone URL: https://code.example.edu/gitlab/some-project.git
SSH Clone URL:  git@code.example.edu:some-project.git
Using LDAP: yes
Using Omniauth: no

GitLab Shell
Version:    1.8.0
Repositories:   /home/git/repositories/
Hooks:      /home/git/gitlab-shell/hooks/
Git:        /usr/bin/git

[git@code gitlab]$ bundle exec rake gitlab:check RAILS_ENV=production
Checking Environment ...

Git configured for git user? ... yes
Has python2? ... yes
python2 is supported version? ... yes

Checking Environment ... Finished

Checking GitLab Shell ...

GitLab Shell version >= 1.7.9 ? ... OK (1.8.0)
Repo base directory exists? ... yes
Repo base directory is a symlink? ... no
Repo base owned by git:git? ... yes
Repo base access is drwxrws---? ... yes
update hook up-to-date? ... yes
update hooks in repos are links: ...
(removed repository list, all were ok)
Running /home/git/gitlab-shell/bin/check
Check GitLab API access: OK
Check directories and files:
    /home/git/repositories: OK
    /home/git/.ssh/authorized_keys: OK
Test redis-cli executable: redis-cli 2.4.10
Send ping to redis server: PONG
gitlab-shell self-check successful

Checking GitLab Shell ... Finished

Checking Sidekiq ...

Running? ... yes
Number of Sidekiq processes ... 1

Checking Sidekiq ... Finished

Checking LDAP ...

LDAP users with access to your GitLab server (limit: 100):
(removed my user list... it printed them just fine)

Checking LDAP ... Finished

Checking GitLab ...

Database config exists? ... yes
Database is SQLite ... no
All migrations up? ... yes
GitLab config exists? ... yes
GitLab config outdated? ... no
Log directory writable? ... yes
Tmp directory writable? ... yes
Init script exists? ... yes
Init script up-to-date? ... no
  Try fixing it:
  Redownload the init script
  For more information see:
  doc/install/installation.md in section "Install Init Script"
  Please fix the error above and rerun the checks.
projects have namespace: ...
(projects all said yes)
projects have satellites? ...
(projects said yes or "can't create, repository is empty")
Redis version >= 2.0.0? ... yes
Your git bin path is "/usr/bin/git"
Git version >= 1.7.10 ? ... yes (1.8.4)

Checking GitLab ... Finished
```

**Partial fix**
The search now works. I had to update the following timout lines:

```
[git@code gitlab]$ grep timeout config/unicorn.rb config/gitlab.yml
config/unicorn.rb:timeout 90
config/gitlab.yml:    # Git timeout to read a commit, in seconds
config/gitlab.yml:    timeout: 90
```

As for the graphs, they are still broken.  Here is the production log while trying to render the graph:

```
Started GET "/gitlab/its-banner/ban8l/graphs/master" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-05 08:06:50 -0500
Processing by Projects::GraphsController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"project_id"=>"its-banner/ban8l", "id"=>"master"}
  Rendered projects/graphs/show.html.haml within layouts/projects (0.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head.html.haml (3.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_broadcast.html.haml (18.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/_search.html.haml (1.6ms)
  Rendered layouts/_head_panel.html.haml (29.4ms)
  Rendered layouts/_init_auto_complete.html.haml (0.7ms)
  Rendered layouts/_flash.html.haml (0.3ms)
  Rendered shared/_no_ssh.html.haml (1.8ms)
  Rendered layouts/nav/_project.html.haml (15.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 456ms (Views: 46.2ms | ActiveRecord: 254.9ms)
Started GET "/gitlab/its-banner/ban8l/graphs/master?_=1391605583275" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-02-05 08:06:51 -0500
Processing by Projects::GraphsController#show as JS
  Parameters: {"_"=>"1391605583275", "project_id"=>"its-banner/ban8l", "id"=>"master"}
  Rendered projects/graphs/show.js.haml (22.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 30217ms (Views: 85.5ms | ActiveRecord: 12.7ms)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add the lines of the production.log that detail the 500 error.

Comment: I updated the issue above, thanks for helping!  Happy to provide more info if needed

Comment: I don't see the 500 error in the log, that is probably because the 500 is due to a timeout as you indicated. I don't have any immediate suggestions.